# Android Fragments saveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been working on changing my application from multiple activities to single activity and multiple fragments. I have Multiple Fragments and Single Activity A.

Following was my scenario when the application had multiple activities.

1. Activity A --> Activity B --> Activity C --> Activity D
2. Web request was sent in all activities for every 60secs on the background and then the UI is updated.
3. I was sending request only in the `onResume()` method and was canceling the request and timer in the `onPause()` method, because of which only the visible activity sends the request and others don't.
4. I saved a boolean value in the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to check whether the request is sent for the first time. Only if it was first time I would show progress bar and then draw the view. If not (if the activity is restored from back stack) the the progress bar is not shown and the UI alone is updated upon successful response.
5. I moved from Activity A to B. Now the web service request was cancelled in the `onPause()` method of Activity A. In Activity B's `onResume()` again a web service was called, progress bar was shown(since its the first time activity is loaded) and the view is drawn. The working is all similar to Activity A.
6. From Activity B I pressed back button and Activity A is resumed. Hence the web service is sent from the `onResume()` method of Activity A. This time I check the savedInstanceState is not null and hence I don't show the progress bar(to allow the user to still move on to acitivy B and on).

Following is what I'm doing right now after implementing Single Activity and Multiple fragment.

1. I'm not replacing any fragment. I'm just adding them.
2. Because of just adding them all fragments are actively sending web service in the time interval.
3. If I replace the fragment instead of adding them, the view is created from the first,which is not what I need.

How can I do this?? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

For the webservice polling create a headless fragment, see: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

This fragment is added in your first activity and the job of the headless fragment is to poll the web service every 60secs just as you do now.

At this point the boolean is not needed anymore, simply do a findFragmentByTag(TAG_OF_HEADLESS_FRAGMENT) and check if it is null to find out whether it is the first time the Activity is started.

Now, to notify whichever fragment that is now visible when it is time to update the UI you need to implement a fragment callback pattern, see: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

With the callback, the flow of communication would be something like:

```
WebPollFragment -> Activity -> B When fragment B is in focus
WebPollFragment -> Activity -> C When fragment C is in focus
WebPollFragment -> Activity -> D And so on...
```

This also illustrates my final advice, which is that you should in my opinion replace the fragments with each other (which you can with the headless fragment doing the background job).

Hope this gets you on the way.

Comment: Yep. That is more or less what I do. I have a single activity with a PagerAdapter and ViewPager to swipe between fragments as the main tab. Then each other tab than the first adds a fragment on top of the whole screen. Selecting another tab replaces the current fragment.